# WooCommerce - stop automatically adding product attributes (tags) to li class on archive page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Our WooCommerce website is running slower than I'd like, and in the process of debugging I've stumbled upon a question...

WooCommerce automatically adds product attributes as classes on the product `<li>` tag in the category archive pages - e.g.
`<li class="post-2000 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-categoryhere product_tag-taghere pa_one-attributehere pa_two-attributehere pa_three-attributehere instock sale featured shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple" id="prod-2000" data-id="2000">`

Due to the large number of product attributes that we use, and the number of products we're showing on each archive page, this is adding up to quite a lot of additional MySQL queries on each page load *(as WooCommerce must run 2 separate DB queries per attribute per product)*.

So - the question - does anyone know of a way to stop Woo adding these classes to each product on the archive page, to *hopefully speed up my page load times?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this myself.

The classes are added with the WP core function post_class(), which in turn calls get_post_class().

As of WP 4.2.0, this latter function also includes all post taxonomies, which is why this is only a recent(ish) issue.

In order to fix this, I have copied both post_class() and get_post_class() into my own functions.php file, renamed them, and customised them to stop it from querying the taxonomies. Then update the WooCommerce template file to call this new function, and voila.

I will run some numbers and comment soon with the improvements in performance for others' reference.

Comment: Numbers finished, this change has removed 500 - 1200 MySQL queries from each page load, depending on the number of attributes on each product on the page, and over 1s off the load time of some pages, so well worth implementing!